# Quickest way to check if an email domain is within a list of domains

Tags: java, arrays, match

I would like to make sure that the email address a client inputs is a business account email as we only work with large companies who have thier own domains.

I have a list of the most common email domains from this site: https://email-verify.my-addr.com/list-of-most-popular-email-domains.php

I would like the quickest way to check that the email has **not** got one of these domains in Java.

```
List<String> domains = ...
String email = "bob@gmail.com";

Boolean domainsMatch = false;

//Some code to check the domains against the email

return !domainMatches;
```

I tried the obvious

```
for (String domain: domains)
{
  if (email.contains(domain)) domainsMatch = true;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a faster more efficient way

Comment: You shouldn't use `contains`, as this could match e.g. `me@notgmail.com` with `gmail.com`.

Comment: you can try with hashsets, they should give you amortized 0(1) instead of for's O(N)

Comment: Have you considered using hashed lookup? A [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) is one that does this.

Comment: @IłyaBursov makes more sense to use HashSet. thanks for the insights

Comment: If you want to "make sure that the email address a client inputs is a business account email", why don't you maintain a whitelist of those domains, instead of a blacklist of popular domains?

Comment: I'd question this approach to begin with. Especially "large companies" may have their own domains. "Popular" freemail services are (most?) oftenly used for private e-mail addresses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are there any statistics to reference, in terms of a _Set_ functioning faster than an array?

Comment: @Reilas a HashSet has amortized constant time lookup; a TreeSet has log time lookup; an array has linear time lookup, because you have to check every element in the worst case.

Comment: There is a more important question here, which is _how are you going to distribute this list of domains_: that is, by what mechanism do you update it when you inevitably find an important customer's domain is missing? Do you have to re-release your software? Can it be updated via a web interface etc. That might be a more important choice to make that some optimization over speed of lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One efficient way which I can think of(provided you're using `Java 8` or later) is the use of ***[`streams api`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams)*** which are especially designed to be more efficient for operations on large data sets.

```java
List<String> domains = ...
String email = "bob@gmail.com";

boolean domainMatches = domains.stream()
    .anyMatch(email::contains);

return !domainMatches;
```

Also, as pointed out by *@AndyTurner*, you shouldn't use `contains` because it can match some invalid address(like `bob@gmailcom`). So if you're looking for another way, you can use equals:

```java
List<String> domains = ...
String email = "bob@gmail.com";

String domain = email.split("@")[1];

boolean domainMatches = domains.stream()
    .anyMatch(domain::equals);

return !domainMatches;
```

- **[Reference 1](https://dzone.com/articles/java-performance-for-looping-vs-streaming)**
- **[Reference 2](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-vs-loops)**

***EDIT:(Recommended approach)***

Based on the comments and after brainstorming I came up with yet another way which is more efficient that using `streams` as well and that is using a `HashSet`. Something like:

```java
List<String> domains = ...
String email = "bob@gmail.com";

Set<String> domainSet = new HashSet<>(domains);
String domain = email.split("@")[1]; // You can also use indexOf and substring.

boolean domainMatches = domainSet.contains(domain);

return !domainMatches;
```

Comment: Please provide more detail on your claim of efficiency.

Comment: based on 2nd reference - non parallel streams are at least 4 times worse than simple for loop

Comment: You could also use `indexOf` and `substring` instead of `split`.

Comment: @MCEmperor thanks. Actually `split` stuck first in my mind generally use it with regexes so does that. You're right though.

Comment: Just use a HashSet for the domains, then you can directly use `contains`. No reason to use a list.

Comment: _"... you shouldn't use `contains` because it can match some invalid address(like `bob@gmailcom`) ..."_, this is not true.  Is this a typo?

Comment: @MCEmperor, _email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1)_.

Comment: And, you should use _domain::equalsIgnoreCase_.

Comment: @Reilas They mean `String::contains` (rather than `HashSet::contains`) there. BTW, `gmail.com@example.com` would also be accepted if using `String::contains` :)

Comment: @Luatic, I don't follow.  The value _"bob@gmailcom"_ should not return _true_ for _"bob@gmail.com"_, whether it be _HashSet_ or _String_.

Comment: @Reilas ah, yeah, it's missing a dot.

Comment: @Luatic, they said, _"... you shouldn't use `contains` because it can match some invalid address(like `bob@gmailcom`) ..."_.  This is incorrect, the value _"bob@gmailcom"_ should not return _true_ for _"bob@gmail.com"_.  And, you're saying that _"... They mean String::contains (rather than HashSet::contains) there."_.  That would not matter, the values are not equal.

Comment: @Reilas Ah indeed, Andy's point was that there could be a prefix of the domain after the `@` that would silently be accepted. You're right, the example should be fixed to be something like `bob@<...>gmail.com` or `<...>gmail.com<...>@<...>`.

Comment: @Luatic, I simply don't follow, you'd need to provide some sort of example.  It's all code-points.  The _contains_ method will just compare the _String_ values.

Comment: @Reilas The op used `email.contains(domain)` in their question. This checks whether the email address contains the domain *anywhere*. So it would also accept "invalid" e-mail addresses such as addresses with a "valid" domain for the "name" (`gmail.com@example.com`) or addresses with domains that contain a "valid" domain (`example@nothisisnotgmail.com`). What the OP should have done instead is to check whether the e-mail *ends with* `@<domain>`, where `<domain>` is a "valid" domain. This is what mandy and Andy are pointing out here.

Comment: @Luatic, I see, _"gmail.com@example.com"_.  I could not understand the error, this makes sense.  I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1):

The [jmail library](https://github.com/RohanNagar/jmail) could do this for you.  Rather than using regex to validate emails, it parses the email into [an object](https://github.com/RohanNagar/jmail/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sanctionco/jmail/Email.java) and then conducts validation on the parts.  It also allows custom validation.

One of the fields of in `Email.java` is `List<String> domainParts`.  This contains all the parts of the domain split by the period (assuming that it parsed properly, otherwise it will fail other validations).  You can add a custom validator to the `EmailValidator` as follows:

```java
public class MyEmailValidator {
  public boolean validateEmail(String email) {
    List<String> invalidDomains = List.of("gmail", "yahoo");
    EmailValidator validator = JMail.strictValidator().withRule(validationEmail -> Collections.disjoint(validationEmail.domainParts(), invalidDomains));
    return validator.isValid(email);
    }
}
```

You can test this easily enough.

```java
@Test
void validateEmail() {
  MyEmailValidator validator = new MyEmailValidator();
  assertTrue(validator.validateEmail("test@my.company.com"));
  assertFalse(validator.validateEmail("test@gmail.com"));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> *"... I would like the quickest way to check that the email has not got one of these domains in Java. ..."*

The *fastest* solution would be a *loop*.

```java
List<String> domains = ...
String email = "bob@gmail.com".toLowerCase(),
       s = email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1);

Boolean domainsMatch = false;

//Some code to check the domains against the email

for (String domain: domains)
{
    if (domain.endsWith(s)) {
        domainsMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}

return domainsMatch;
```

Alternately, use a *stream*.

```java
List<String> domains = ...
String email = "bob@gmail.com".toLowerCase(),
       s = email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1);

//Some code to check the domains against the email

Boolean noMatch
    = domains.stream()
             .noneMatch(x -> x.toLowerCase().endsWith(s));
```